# Why does Protagonist choose a risky place to do pull-ups?

Tags: tenet

Here we can see Protagonist choose an elevated ladder to do pull-ups:

[image: Protagonist doing pull-ups on an elevated ladder]

Why does Protagonist choose such a risky place to do pull-ups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [this Reddit question](https://www.reddit.com/r/tenet/comments/l509oz/the_protagonist_does_pullups_twice_during_the/?utm_medium=android_app&utm_source=share), he's actually doing chin-ups (it's a matter of the grip), but the script does state pull-ups, which he does twice, once in regular time and once in inverted time. The script does not state why he did them there, but does place that first scene right after Protagonist considers his suicide pills, so I believe that this is an indication that Protagonist has a lower regards for his life than the average person. In comparison, in the later scene, he is doing those chin-ups from a much safer position, albeit one not physically very distant from the initial ladder.

Comment: “which he does twice, once in regular time and once in inverted time” — surely in inverted time they're push-downs?